# Add search to the Drupal 7 find content

Tags: 7, nodes

By default drupal 7 find content page comes with filter by type and status. I wanted to give one more filter, where user can type the few letters from the title they are looking for so that they can find the article/page with ease even when theres 100's of content in the site.

I did something similar using views and exposing title as a filter. But it would be great to add this field and search to the default filters we find in the drupal 7 find content page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module:

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability.

It will let you replace the standard content admin page with a view, to which you can add as many filters as you need.

Comment: This was so much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Find Content](https://drupal.org/project/find_content), simpler and newer than Administration Views.

> Adds a search box to the Find Content screen
>
> *Requires: Node (enabled), Field (enabled), Field SQL storage (enabled)*

Comment: I tried this but found it lacking because it doesn't support pagination properly. If you search for Contact and in page 1 of your default list you have a page called Contact Us and on page 2 of those results you have a page called Contacts it won't show Contacts until you navigate to the still showing pagination.  Not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's admin accessible area and instead of modifying it why don't you try  search module with [Search Autocomplete](http://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) module

hope it will help you :)